# Example of an antipodal set

Tags: general-topology, convex-geometry, discrete-geometry

So I am trying to solve the mentioned homework question:

**Find an example of an antipodal set of size $2^d$.**

The antipodal set is a finite set $F$ of points in $R^d$ such that for any two points $f_1,f_2$ there are two distinct parallel hyperplanes $H_1, H_2$ such $f_i  \in H_i$ and $F  \subset Conv(H_1 \cup H_2$)
for example, the triangle is an antipodal set because for any two points there are two parallel hyperplanes also parallelogram

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a strange idea to me. I'm familiar with antipodal points on spheres, or even antipodal points on a convex polygon, but it's unclear to me what an antipodal set is

Comment: @user20672 I agree even I very new to this and I did not find much information about it either.

Comment: Is the homework problem from a book? Or is it based on a lecture?

Comment: @user20672 it's an assignment problem.

Comment: Did you discuss antipodal sets in the lecture? Are there lecture notes? I'm really curious to know how this idea is defined too :)

Comment: @user20672 No proper lecture notes. Antipodal points was used to prove another conjecture as far as I remember. But I will through my notes again and will edit them if I find anything new

Comment: @user20672 I have edited it. I hope it answers your question.

Comment: When you say the triangle is an antipodal set, do you mean the vertices of the triangle are an antipodal set?

Comment: @user20672 yup you can consider them as antipodal sets

Comment: @EthanBolker sounds good! Even I think an n-dimensional hyperrectangle is also a good example.

Comment: @EthanBolker yes you are absolutely correct according to the Dancer-Grunbrum theorem $2^d$ is maximal for antipodal sets in $R^d$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am reading the definition correctly then the vertices of the unit cube in dimension $d$ form such a set. The two parallel hyperplanes will contain opposite faces of the cube whose dimension depends on the dimension of the smallest face containing the two points.

Imagine the possibilities in the plane and space to see the geometry.

I wonder if size $2^d$ is maximal for antipodal sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$.